# how to replace multiple integers values using regex in pandas

Tags: regex

Only using regex

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'Weight': [234, 54, 246, 754, 686, 335]})
data = data.replace({'Weight': r'[1-999]'},"one", regex=True)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```py
df["Weight"] = df["Weight"].astype(str)                      # convert to string
df["Weight"] = df["Weight"].str.replace('^\d{1,3}$', 'one')  # apply regex
```